# Opening ArcGIS Pro layer in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-pro, chart, layer-file

I received a layer package (lpkx) from a client. Finding out I couldn't open it in ArcMap led me to discover that this is a newer version of the software (ArcGIS Pro).

I managed to install that and license it. But once I opened it in ArcGIS Pro I quickly found out that the functionality to add proportional piecharts is not (yet) implemented in Pro, so I can't do the things I need to do.

Now it appears that the entire file from the client is useless, as I can't open it in ArcMap either.

Are there any possible fixes?

Comment: You could export your layers to datasets on your computer and then use those in ArcMap.  You could alternately add the datasets to ArcMap from where they are stored, which is probably in your user folder; look up the source location in Pro.  If there is a lot of work needed to symbolize your layers to match those in Pro that might require some manual work, although you could save the symbols and then use those in ArcMap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you "opened [the LPKX file] in ArcGIS Pro [and] found out that the functionality to add proportional piecharts is not (yet) implemented" I think you must have been using a version from before ArcGIS Pro supported [chart symbology](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/layer-properties/chart-symbology.htm):

> A chart is a type of statistical graphic that represents data. Charts
> can be used as multivariate symbology in ArcGIS Pro to show
> quantitative differences between attributes, with each part of the
> chart representing an attribute value that contributes to the overall
> whole set of values. Chart symbology can be used with point, line, or
> polygon features.

Consequently, I think the reason you were investigating opening an LPKX file in ArcMap,  no longer applies.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't need the symbology that is packaged with the layer, you can simply unzip/decompress the lpkx and grab the FileGeoDatabase within that contains the data.

As for the symbology, you'd need to publish the LPKX to ArcGIS Online and then download the symbology from there.

So, no easy work-arounds, but you do have access to the data itself from within the lpkx without much hassle.

Answer (score 3):

Layer Package is just zip archive and the file geodatabase is inside it along with LYR file